# Laravel create project error: Unable to find the wrapper

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to create a project in laravel by using `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`, but it seems it has the error. Actually the first error is just like this

`The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection`

and then I soved it but not secure by using this

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

and now it displaying some warnings on my command and then when I create new project the error display like on the image below. it would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer into your console error message, it says "`...You must enable the openssl extension to download ....`"

And, the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#server-requirements) also says, you need to enable the below extensions.

`OpenSSL PHP Extension`

So, you solution is to simply enable the extension by going into your `pho.ini` fine. If you are using xampp, you can go to `C:\xampp\php` and find `php.ini` and change the following line:

`;extension=openssl`

To
`extension=openssl`